# Deleted by mistake all logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logins

By mistake I deleted all logins from SQL Server 2008R (dev machine) Now I have only one login `sa`. When I try to connect to any database it shows me that my user does not have permission, so I can't even connect using my windows account.

How can I recover all logins?

What should I do?

I don't have a backup but I do have a production environment that is configured the same way as dev was.

Comment: have you a backup of all db included system db?

Comment: no, but i have production environment as same as dev

Comment: [How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server)

Comment: You can also use this script if you need to keep them in sync: https://straightpathsql.com/archives/2016/07/robert-davis-login-script-free-dba-tool-week/

Comment: After copying the logins, use this incident as an *excellent* learning opportunity about backups and restores.

Comment: i cant login to sql machine with my user, in security -> login  i have only ONE login sa

Comment: Are you saying that you can't access any of the DBs even as `sa`? Can you access `master` at least?

Comment: How can you see the login if you can't login?

Comment: SA hadn't removed

Answer (score 1):

founded solution 
soure 1 ) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddKWtvz6aMw
soure 2 ) https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sqlman/2011/06/14/tips-tricks-you-have-lost-access-to-sql-server-now-what/